# bootstrap 3 collapsible not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap 3.0.2 in that collapsible plugin is not working when i incorporated code into my file. i have added bootstrap.js after jquery.js.
i am not able to understand why this is not working, do i need to include any other file.
any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>On Demand Delivery</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
     </h4>
   </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
     <div class="panel-body">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
       Collapsible Group Item #2
       </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">
       Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 </div>

 <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: works great here http://jsfiddle.net/FL7dA/ you getting any err in console?

Comment: May be you have missed something, Are you able to show the link?

Comment: @Yashhy i am not getting any error. you tried with diff code. you fiddle has 3 tabs

Comment: @SurjithSM i have included bootstrap.js and HTML code is  here anything else is required.

Comment: @Ghan The code you given is working fine, can you upload it in a server and show me the link? So that I can debug it.

Comment: @SurjithSM yes i have also tried the same HTML in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FL7dA/1/ in that it is working fine. but code at my side does not work. even i tried with bootstrap.js from JSfiddle but no luck. can you please suggest something.

Comment: @Ghan Are you able to show the link?

Comment: @Ghan working with two or three tabs doesn't matter, make sure you bootstrap files are loaded properly.

Comment: @SurjithSM No i am not able to share, but all the code is same as in que.

Comment: @Ghan OK, What do you mean by not working? Can you explain it?

Comment: @Ghan can u please create a new html based on this http://jsfiddle.net/FL7dA/2/ and say whether its running perfectly in local..?

Comment: @SurjithSM hey I found it. It was a js path problem. thanks fro your time.

Comment: @Ghan ok, but always use **'Network'** tab in google chrome console and make sure all your js/css/bootstrap files are loaded properly.